# Elm: Parsing a status code (with a potential error message) in JSON

Tags: json, elm

I've been having a bit of difficulty wrapping my head around parsing JSON with Elm. I seem to have the basics down, but for some reason this small piece of JSON has left me stumped.

Here's the scenario: I am posting to a JSON API which will return with one of the two formats:

*If the request is successful:*

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "post": { ... }
}
```

*If it fails:*

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "message": "Some error message"
}
```

I'm trying to encode this JSON response into these data types:

```
type RequestStatus = Success | Error String


type alias CreatePostResponse =
    { status : RequestStatus
    , post : Maybe Post }
```

So far I've had no luck. I've been looking through the [JSON.Decode](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/json.html) tutorial and [this Thoughtbot article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/decoding-json-structures-with-elm) as guides, but neither seem to gotten me to the right place. Here's the code I have so far:

```
createPostResponse : Decoder CreatePostResponse
createPostResponse =
    succeed CreatePostResponse
    |: (("status" := string) `andThen` (("error" := string) `andThen` decodeStatus))
    |: maybe ("post" := post)


decodeStatus : String -> String -> Decoder RequestStatus
decodeStatus status errorMessage = 
    succeed (case status of
        "success" -> Success
        "error" -> Error errorMessage
        _ -> Error "unknown")
```

Obviously this produces all sorts of type errors and doesn't compile, but I haven't been able to come up with a good way to get the string from the "message" field into the `RequestStatus` type.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a little working piece of code which should do what you are after. I've taken the liberty of assuming a basic shape for the `Post` type, for concreteness.

```
import Json.Decode exposing (..)

type alias Post = { title: String, body: String }

type RequestStatus = Success Post | Error String

post: Decoder Post
post = object2 Post ("title" := string) ("body" := string)

requestStatusData: String -> Decoder RequestStatus
requestStatusData status =
    case status of
    "success" -> object1 Success ("post" := post)
    "error" -> object1 Error ("message" := string)
    _ -> fail <| status ++ " is not a valid value for request status"

decodeStatus : Decoder RequestStatus
decodeStatus =
    ("status" := string) `andThen` requestStatusData
```

First, I turned the `RequestStatus` and `CreatePostResponse` types inside-out: instead of `CreatePostResponse` having a `RequestStatus` and a `Maybe Post`, which need to be kept in-sync with one another, the `RequestStatus` type itself models the fact that a success has a post, while an error does not. The new `RequestStatus` reads more like idiomatic Elm.

I then approached the decoding from the top-down:

1. To decode some JSON into a `RequestStatus`, we first deserialize the `"status"` property in the JSON object as a string, then we deserialize the rest based on what `"status"` was. The idiomatic way of doing this is with `andThen` (it looks like you knew this, but hadn't quite perfected the way it fit in with the rest). This translates to:

   ```
   decodeStatus : Decoder RequestStatus
   decodeStatus =
       ("status" := string) `andThen` requestStatusData
   ```
2. `andThen` decodes one record, then passes that record into a function which does the rest of the decoding, so `requestStatusData` needs to look like:

   ```
   requestStatusData: String -> Decoder RequestStatus
   ```

   `requestStatusData` is either a `Success Post` or a `Error String`. So we need two branches, then, associated with statuses `"success"` and `"error"` (plus a default to catch malformed statuses):

   ```
   requestStatusData status =
       case status of
       "success" -> makeSuccessWithPost
       "error" -> makeErrorWithString
       _ -> fail <| status ++ " is not a valid value for request status"
   ```
3. We fill out the `makeSuccessWithPost` and `makeErrorWithString` implementations. The `objectN` functions in `Json.Decode` provide a facility to decode components, then feed them to a constructor (or other function):

   ```
   object1 Success ("post" := post)
   ```

   first decodes the `"post"` property using the decoder defined as `post`, then invokes the first argument of `object1` (`Success`) on the result. Likewise,

   ```
   object2 Post ("title" := string) ("body" := string)
   ```

   decodes `"title"` using the `string` decoder, then decodes `"body"` using the `string` decoder, then invokes the `Post` function with the two decoded strings as its arguments. So we end up with:

   ```
   requestStatusData status =
       case status of
       "success" -> object1 Success ("post" := post)
       "error" -> object1 Error ("message" := string)
       _ -> fail <| status ++ " is not a valid value for request status"
   ```
4. The last step is filling out the `post` decoder, which as mentioned above is a standard application of `object2`.

Overall, I *think* I've gone about this in fairly standard, idiomatic Elm style, but I'm quite new and I might have made some gaffes. It does work though! One last note: I would argue that the `RequestStatus` type is not actually necessary; the `Result` type in the Elm core library captures the idea of a type with a success and failure mode. You could use

```
Result String Post
```

instead of `RequestStatus` without losing any functionality (you'd need to change `requestStatusData` slightly but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader...).

Comment: Yep! This ended up working great for me. Thank you so much for taking the time to write this out (and hopefully plenty of confused elmers in the future will be guided by this).

For the record, I did end up changing my `RequestStatus` type to alias `Result String Post` – great suggestion!

Comment: Glad to help. It's a good way for me to consolidate my understanding of Elm too. Once you get to grips with the concepts, it's a lovely tidy way to deserialize JSON into sophisticated types.